# ¿Cómo recorrer un árbol binario buscando nodos con el mismo dato?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Nodo {
public:
    string cadena;
    int vecesRepetidas;// se usara solo para la lista de palabras repetidas

    Nodo *izquierda, *derecha;

    Nodo(string cad): cadena(cad), izquierda(NULL), derecha(NULL){}
    Nodo(string cd, int veces): cadena(cd), vecesRepetidas(veces), izquierda(NULL), derecha(NULL){}
};

class Arbol {
public:
    Nodo *raiz;
    int cont;

    void insertar(Nodo *nuevo);
    void mostrarPreorden(Nodo *r);
    void repetidos(Nodo *r);

    Arbol(): raiz(NULL), cont(0){}
};
void Arbol::insertar(Nodo *nuevo){
Nodo *n = new Nodo(nuevo->cadena);

string temp;

if(raiz == NULL){
    raiz = nuevo;
}else{
    Nodo *aux = raiz;
    Nodo *padre;
    while(true){
        padre = aux;

        if( n->cadena < aux->cadena ){
            aux = aux->izquierda;
            if(aux == NULL){
                padre->izquierda = n;
                break;// finaliza el metodo
            }
        }else{

            aux = aux->derecha;

            if(aux == NULL){
                padre->derecha = n;
                break; // finaliza el metodo
            }
        }
    }
}
}
void Arbol::mostrarPreorden(Nodo *r){
if( r != NULL ){
    cout<<r->cadena<<endl;
    mostrarPreorden(r->izquierda);
    mostrarPreorden(r->derecha);
}
}

void Arbol::repetidos(Nodo *r){

if( r != NULL ){
    if( r->cadena == raiz->cadena ){
        cont++;
    }

    repetidos(r->izquierda);
    repetidos(r->derecha);
}

cout<<"la raiz se repite "<<cont<<endl;
}

int main()
{
Nodo *aux;
Arbol arbol;
string palabra;

char resp[3];
do{
    int opc;
    cout<<"------------- MENU --------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"     1. anadir un nodo "<<endl;
    cout<<"     2. mostrar nodos"<<endl;
    cout<<"     3. mostrar repetidos de la raiz"<<endl;
    cin>>opc;

    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            cout<<"\ndigite la palabra a agregar"<<endl;
            cin>>palabra;

            aux = new Nodo(palabra);
            arbol.insertar(aux);

            break;
        case 2:
            arbol.mostrarPreorden(arbol.raiz);
            break;
        case 3:
            arbol.repetidos(arbol.raiz);
            break;

    }

    cout<<"Desea volver a ingresar otra palabra? (s/n)"<<endl;
    cin>>resp;
    system("cls");
}while( resp[0] == 'S' || resp[0] == 's' );

return 0;
}
```

La idea es que diga cuantas veces se repite cada nodo. En este caso cada nodo tiene un string, entonces debe decir cuantas veces se repite cada palabra almacenada en cada uno de los nodos. Hasta ahora solo he podido hacer que diga cuantas veces se repite la raíz, y el resultado no es muy bueno que digamos.

Answer (score 15):

#### Problema.

> hasta ahora solo he podido hacer que diga cuantas veces se repite la raiz

Es normal, puesto que sólo buscas **la raíz**:

```
arbol.repetidos(arbol.raiz);
```

Si quieres buscar datos arbitrarios deberías solicitar el dato a buscar no el dato almacenado en la raíz. Así que tu función de búsqueda debería recibir el dato a buscar no el nodo desde el que buscar; una vez sabido lo que quieres buscar puedes lanzar una búsqueda recursiva.

---

Por otro lado, evita usar una variable de instancia (`int Arbol::cont`) para realizar el recuento, es propenso a errores:

- **No le das valor inicial**: ¡`Arbol` no tiene constructor!.
- **No restableces el valor a `0` cuando inicias la búsqueda**: así que llamadas consecutivas a `Arbol::repetidos` sólo aumenta el recuento.
- **No podrías hacer llamadas simultáneas**: el recuento se almacena en una variable compartida si buscases en diferentes hilos obtendrías valores absurdos.

#### Propuesta.

Elimina `int Arbol::cont` y cambia la función de búsqueda para recibir el texto a buscar y crea una función recursiva que reciba tanto la palabra buscada como el nodo desde el que buscar:

```
int Arbol::repetidos(const string &palabra){
    return repetidos_desde(raiz, palabra);
}

int Arbol::repetidos_desde(const Nodo *const nodo, const std::string &palabra)
{
    if (nodo)
    {
        return repetidos_desde(nodo->izquierda, palabra) +
               repetidos_desde(nodo->derecha, palabra) +
               (nodo->cadena == cadena ? 1 : 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Con `Arbol::repetidos` podemos contar desde la raiz una cadena, esta función llama a `Arbol::repetidos_desde` recursivamente la cual devuelve el recuento de la cadena facilitada contando desde el nodo indicado por lo que sólo debemos sumar el retorno de dicha función.

Con estos cambios, en `main` podrás buscar directamente las palabras:

```
switch(opc){
    case 1:
        cout<<"\ndigite la palabra a agregar\n";
        cin>>palabra;

        aux = new Nodo(palabra);
        arbol.insertar(aux);
        break;
    case 2:
        arbol.mostrarPreorden(arbol.raiz);
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"\ndigite la palabra a buscar\n";
        cin>>palabra;
        cout<<palabra<<" se repite: "<<arbol.repetidos(palabra)<<" veces\n";
        break;
}
```

#### Ejemplo.

En <kbd>[esta versión simplificada de tu código](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ngJDlNCBYI30uRZO)</kbd>:

```
struct Nodo
{
    std::string cadena{};
    Nodo *izquierda{nullptr}, *derecha{nullptr};
    ~Nodo() { delete izquierda; delete derecha; }
};

int main()
{
    Nodo raiz
    {
        "patata",
        new Nodo { "frita",   new Nodo{"patata"}, new Nodo{"berenjena"} },
        new Nodo { "hervida", new Nodo{"patata"}, new Nodo{"zanahoria", new Nodo{"patata"}} }
    };

    std::cout << busqueda_recursiva(&raiz, "patata") << '\n';
    std::cout << busqueda_recursiva(&raiz, "berenjena") << '\n';
    std::cout << busqueda_recursiva(&raiz, "zanahoria") << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

El resultado de buscar `"patata"` es 4, mientras que `"berenjena"` y `"zanahoria"` devuelven 1. La estructura creada en memoria es la siguiente:

[image]
Así que buscando desde la raíz nos encuentra:

- **`patata`**
- `patata` → `hervida` → **`patata`**
- `patata` → `hervida` → `patata` → **`patata`**
- `patata` → `frita` → **`patata`**

Buscando `busqueda_recursiva(raiz.izquierda, "patata")` el resultado sería `2`.

Answer (score 5):

Me declaro firme defensor de *reinventar la rueda*. El proceso es divertido, y siempre aprendemos algo, aún cuando nos equivoquemos. Propongo una lectura interesante:

[97 cosas que todo programador debería saber. Punto 84 - Reinventa la rueda frecuentemente.](http://97cosas.com/programador/reinventa-rueda-frecuentemente.html)

He observado que las respuestas son más o menos *canónicas*, recorriendo los nodos según sus atributos lógicos. Muestro un método alternativo: vamos a trabajar con los atributos *físicos* de los nodos.

¿ Que no tienen ? claro que si. Tienen varios. Su posición en memória, y el tipo de sus datos internos.

El objetivo de esto es **acelerar significativamente** las búsquedas, **a costa de ralentizar todo lo demás**. No obstante, responderemos **literalmente** a la pregunta. Recorreremos los nodos, pero en un orden concreto, **independiente** de sus atributos internos.

Por cuestiones de claridad del código, voy a utilizar directamente los tipos `size_t` y `ptrdiff_t`; me consta que esto *resta* portabilidad, pero funcionar, funciona. Así nos ahorramos cosas como

```
typedef typename PLANTILLA< ARGUMENTOS >::size_type Size;
```

que pueden resultar confusas para los pocos conocedores del lenguaje, y distraen de la lógica empleada.

Mi método se basa en almacenar los nodos de forma que estén **contiguos en memoria**. Un árbol típico se nos muestra así:

```
  A
  /\
  B C
    /\
    B A
```

La ubicación en memoria seria *mas o menos* aleatoria:

```
  [B]...[A]...[B][C]...[A]
```

Sin embargo, es posible mantenerlos en memoria de forma **contigua** y **ordenada**:

```
  [A][A][B][B][C]
```

Esta organización nos permite realizar **búsquedas binarias**, disminuyendo el tiempo requerido para contar los elementos. Pasamos de complejidad `O( n )` (al recorrer **todos** los nodos) a la mucho *mas mejor* `O( log2 n + 1)`. No es exacto puesto que dependente del número de elementos repetidos. Cuantos mas elementos repetidos tengamos, más tiempo consumimos al contarlos. No obstante, el **peor caso posible**, que todos los nodos tengan el mismo valor, utiliza **el mismo tiempo** que los métodos basados en punteros.

A continuación, el código; funcional y verificable. Creo que está suficientemente comentado:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // rand( ) y srand( ).

struct Nodo {
  std::string cadena;
  // Usamos índices, NO punteros.
  // Para poder hacer iterator <-> índice, usamos ptrdiff_t.
  std::ptrdiff_t izq, der; 

  Nodo( std::string cad ) :
    cadena( cad ),
    izq( -1 ),
    der( -1 ) {
  }
  // Necesario para usar las funciones de C++ que trabajan con
  // secuencias ordenadas.
  bool operator<( const Nodo &otro ) const {
    return cadena < otro.cadena;
  }
};

class Arbol {
private:
  // Para mantener los nodos contiguos en memoria.
  std::vector< Nodo > _vector;
  // NO NECESITAMOS RAIZ para insertar y contar.
  // No obstante, la usaremos, para mostrar como hacerlo.
  std::ptrdiff_t _raiz;

  // Coloca el nodo indicado en la estructura lógica del árbol.
  // HE DECIDIDO que sea aleatoria. Escogemos aleatoriamente
  // entre 'izq' y 'der', busamos el primer nodo que tenga ese
  // atributo libre, y lo enlazamos ahí.
  void colocar( ptrdiff_t );

public:
  Arbol( ) : _vector( ), _raiz( -1 ) { }

  void insertar( const std::string & );
  std::ptrdiff_t cuenta( const std::string & ) const;

  void dump_vector( void ) const;
  // Esto está aquí para facilitar el uso.
  Arbol &operator<<( const std::string &val ) {
    insertar( val );
    return *this;
  }
};

void Arbol::colocar( ptrdiff_t idx ) {
  bool izq = rand( ) & 1;
  std::vector< Nodo >::iterator iter = _vector.begin( );

  // ES IMPOSIBLE QUE TODOS LOS NODOS TENGAN AMBOS
  // 'HIJOS' OCUPADOS.
  while( true ) {
    if( izq && ( iter->izq == -1 ) ) {
      iter->izq = idx;
      break;
    }
    if( ( !izq ) && ( iter->der == -1 ) ) {
      iter->der = idx;
      break;
    }

    ++iter;
  }
}

void Arbol::insertar( const std::string &val ) {
  Nodo aux( val );
  /*
    Los nodos están agrupados por valor.
    Si el valor del nuevo nodo está repetido,
  lo colocamos AL FINAL del grupo, con el objetivo de
  tener que mover menos elementos para hacerle sitio.
  */

  // Para evitar invalidar los iteradores, nos aseguramos
  // de que tengamos espacio para 1 nodo mas.
  _vector.reserve( _vector.size( ) + 1 );

  /*
    CASO ESPECIAL. Primera insercción, la raiz.
  */
  if( _raiz == -1 ) {
    _raiz = 0;
    _vector.push_back( aux );
    return;
  }

  // Inserciones posteriores.
  std::vector< Nodo >::iterator iter;
  std::ptrdiff_t idx;

  // Búsqueda binaria de un nodo con el mismo valor.
  // Devuelve la posición POSTERIOR al nodo; si no hay, es la
  // posición en la que debería de estar. Si hay varias, es la
  // posición en la que insertarlo, después del último.
  iter = std::upper_bound( _vector.begin( ), _vector.end( ), aux );

  /*
    Caso fácil. Añadir al final.
    No hay que modificar ningún nodo anterior, ni '_raiz'.
  */
  if( iter == _vector.end( ) ) {
    idx = _vector.size( );
    _vector.push_back( aux );
    colocar( idx );
    return;
  }

  /*
    El 'meollo' del asunto. Insertar no al final.
    HAY que modificar los índices de los nodos afectados.
    PUEDE que tengamos que modificar '_raiz'.
  */

  _vector.insert( iter, aux );

  // Obtenemos el índice correspondiente a la posición del iterador.
  idx = std::distance( _vector.begin( ), iter );

  // Recorremos TODOS los nodos, actualizando sus índices.
  // Si en cada determinado nodo, 'izq' o 'der' apuntan MAS ALLÁ
  // del índice en el que colocamos el nuevo valor, tenemos que
  // sumar 1 a sus índices, para que sigan apuntando correctamente. 
  iter = _vector.begin( );
  while( iter != _vector.end( ) ) {
    if( iter->izq >= idx )
      ++iter->izq;

    if( iter->der >= idx )
      ++iter->der;

    ++iter;
  }

  // Lo mismo con '_raiz'. Si apunta MÁS ALLÁ de la posición del nuevo
  // índice, le sumamos 1.    
  if( _raiz >= idx )
    ++ _raiz;

  colocar( idx );
}

std::ptrdiff_t Arbol::cuenta( const std::string &val ) const {
  std::pair< std::vector< Nodo >::const_iterator, std::vector< Nodo >::const_iterator > rango;

  // Obtenemos el rango (inicio, fin] en el que están contenidos todos los
  // valores iguales al pasado como argumento.
  rango = std::equal_range( _vector.begin( ), _vector.end( ), Nodo( val ) );

  // El número de ocurrencias es 'inicio - fin'.
  return rango.second - rango.first;
}

void Arbol::dump_vector( ) const {
  std::vector< Nodo >::const_iterator iter = _vector.begin( );

  std::cout << "Raiz: [" << _raiz << "]" << std::endl << std::endl;

  while( iter != _vector.end( ) ) {

    std::cout << "[" << iter - _vector.begin( ) << "]" << iter->cadena << "[";
    std::cout << iter->izq << "][" << iter->der << "]" << std::endl;
    ++ iter;
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  static const std::string REPETIDA( "cadena repetida" );
  Arbol arbol;

  std::srand( 0 ); // Así repetimos los resultados.

  // Como usamos índices, tenemos que introducir los elementos
  // 1 a 1.
  arbol << "RAIZ"; // al ser el primero, es la raiz.
  arbol << "cadena2" << REPETIDA << "cadena4" << REPETIDA;
  arbol << "cadena6" << "cadena7" << "cadena8" << REPETIDA;
  arbol << "cadena10" << REPETIDA << "cadena12" << REPETIDA;
  arbol << "cadena14";

  /*
  arbol <<"RAIZ" ); // al ser el primero, es la raiz.
  arbol.insertar( "cadena2" );
  arbol.insertar( REPETIDA );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena4" );
  arbol.insertar( REPETIDA );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena6" );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena7" );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena8" );
  arbol.insertar( REPETIDA );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena10" );
  arbol.insertar( REPETIDA );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena12" );
  arbol.insertar( REPETIDA );
  arbol.insertar( "cadena14" );
  */

  std::cout << "Volcado del vector:" << std::endl;
  arbol.dump_vector( );
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Repeticiones de <abcde>: " << arbol.cuenta( "abcde" ) << std::endl; // 0.
  std::cout << "Repeticiones de <cadena7>: " << arbol.cuenta( "cadena7") << std::endl; // 1.
  std::cout << "Repeticiones de <REPETIDA>: " << arbol.cuenta( REPETIDA ) << std::endl; // 5.

  return 0;
}
```

**EDITO**

Mi propuesta permite seguir utilizando el `Arbol` integrado con todos los algoritmos presentes en C++. Basta con realizar un `iterator` personalizado. Es perfectamente posible, pero la respuesta ya se extendió demasiado. Lo dejamos para otra ocasión ;-)

**EDITO 2**

Compilado con `g++ -std=c++98 -Wall`.

Comment: Da gusto cuando hay más de una respuesta en los temas de c++. Y si ya disponen de cierta calidad ya ni te cuento.

Comment: Viniendo de ti, me siento mas que alagado. Efectivamente, la competencia es sana y divertida.  Y siempre aprendo algo.

Answer (score 3):

Siempre he sido partidario de no reinventar la rueda. La *STL* dispone multitud de funciones que pueden ser utilizadas. Funciones que normalmente han sido pensadas por gente con más conocimientos que nosotros, sobre la función a realizar.

Implementar el conteo directamente en el árbol no es una buena idea porque te hace replantearte una algoritmia que está programada.

Mi planteamiento pasaría por crear un iterador que sea capaz de moverse por los diferentes nodos del árbol y hacer uso de la función `std::count_if` para realizar el conteo.

Los cambios a realizar serían los siguientes:

**1. Los nodos necesitan un puntero al padre**

Esto es así porque para iterar entre los nodos, a veces, será necesario acceder al padre (por ejemplo, para ir del nodo de la derecha al de la izquierda).

```
struct Nodo {

  string cadena;
  int vecesRepetidas; // Se usará solo para la lista de palabras repetidas

  Nodo *izquierda, *derecha, *padre;

  Nodo(string cad, Nodo* padre = NULL)
    : cadena(cad),
      izquierda(NULL),
      derecha(NULL),
      padre(padre)
  {}

  Nodo(string cd, int veces, Nodo* padre = NULL)
    : cadena(cd),
      vecesRepetidas(veces),
      izquierda(NULL),
      derecha(NULL),
      padre(padre)
  {}
};
```

A mi juicio, si todos los miembros del objeto son públicos, entonces estamos ante una estructura, no una clase. De ahí que haya renombrado el tipo del objeto.

**2. Creamos el iterador**

Los iteradores deberían, en teoría, heredar de `std::iterator`, pero no es mi intención dar en esta respuesta un tutorial de varias páginas sobre cómo y por qué funcionan los iteradores, sino que pretendo más dar un enfoque práctico.

En este caso voy a implementar únicamente los métodos imprescindibles para la tarea. El iterador podría quedar entonces así:

```
class ArbolIterator
{
    Nodo* nodo;

  public:

    // Constructor
    ArbolIterator(Nodo* nodo)
      : nodo(nodo)
    {}

    // Operador pre-incremento
    ArbolIterator& operator++()
    {
      if( nodo )
      {
        if( nodo->derecha )
        {
          nodo = nodo->derecha;
          while(true)
          {
            if( nodo->izquierda )
              nodo = nodo->izquierda;
            else
              break;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          Nodo* padre = nodo->padre;
          if( !padre )
            nodo = NULL;
          else
          {
            if( padre->izquierda == nodo )
              nodo = padre;
            else
            {
              nodo = padre;
              while(nodo)
              {
                Nodo* padre = nodo->padre;
                if( padre )
                {
                  if( padre->izquierda == nodo )
                  {
                    nodo = padre;
                    break;
                  }
                  if( padre && padre->derecha != nodo )
                  {
                    nodo = padre->derecha;
                    break;
                  }
                }
                nodo = padre;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return *this;
    }

    // Comparación de dos iteradores
    bool operator==(ArbolIterator it) const
    { return nodo == *it; }

    // Comparación de dos iteradores
    bool operator!=(ArbolIterator it) const
    { return nodo != *it; }

    // Acceso al elemento apuntado por el iterador
    Nodo* operator*() const
    { return nodo; }
};
```

En este caso, el iterador, recorrerá el árbol del nodo más pequeño al más grande. Es decir, para el siguiente árbol:

```
         A
      /     \
    B         C
   / \       /
  D   E     F
 / \   \   / \
G   H   I J   K
```

La secuencia de iteración será:

```
G - D - H - B - E - I - A - J - F - K - C
```

Un requisito adicional para poder ejecutar `std::count_if` es crear una especialización de `std::iterator_traits`. El único requisito que se nos exige en este caso es proporcionar un tipo para `difference_type`. Este tipo será el que empleará la *STL* para calcular la distancia entre dos nodos. Este aspecto no reviste demasiadas implicaciones, para ser coherentes con la mayoría de iteradores devolvemos `size_t`, que en 32 bits es un alias equivalente a `unsigned int`:

```
namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct iterator_traits<ArbolIterator>
  {
    typedef size_t difference_type;
  };
}
```

**3. Actualizar el árbol para que devuelva iteradores**

Ya tenemos nuestra clase para iterar... Ahora tenemos que conseguir que la clase `Arbol` devuelva el juego de iteradores correspondiente mediante los métodos `begin()` y `end()`:

```
class Arbol {
  public:

    ArbolIterator begin()
    {
      Nodo* nodo = raiz;
      if( nodo )
      {
        while( nodo->izquierda )
          nodo = nodo->izquierda;
      }
      return ArbolIterator(nodo);
    }

    ArbolIterator end()
    { return ArbolIterator(NULL); }
};
```

El primer elemento a iterar será, en base a la secuencia explicada en el punto anterior, aquel que se encuentra más a la izquierda.

El último elemento será `NULL`. En el caso de los iteradores, se asume que el rango a iterar es `begin()<=it<end()`. Es decir, `end()` debe apuntar al primer elemento no válido del rango... En este caso será un puntero nulo, lo que indica que el nodo no pertenece al árbol.

Por supuesto, para que el iterador pueda hacer su trabajo es necesario que la clase `Arbol` indique cuál es el padre de cada nodo. Esto se puede conseguir fácilmente editando el método `Arbol::insertar()`:

```
void Arbol::insertar(Nodo *nuevo){
  Nodo *n = new Nodo(nuevo->cadena);

  string temp;

  if(raiz == NULL){
    raiz = nuevo;
  }else{
    Nodo *aux = raiz;
    Nodo *padre;
    while(true){
      padre = aux;

      if( n->cadena < aux->cadena ){
        aux = aux->izquierda;
        if(aux == NULL){
          padre->izquierda = n;
          n->padre = padre; // <<--- AQUI!!!
          break;
        }
      }else{

        aux = aux->derecha;

        if(aux == NULL){
          padre->derecha = n;
          n->padre = padre;  // <<--- AQUI!!!
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**4. Función de comparación**

La función `std::count_if` es la que nos va a requerir otra función que indique si un objeto de tipo `Nodo*` cumple cierta condición o no. La complejidad de la función es que su implementación debería ser tal que:

```
bool func(Nodo* a)
{ return a->cadena == nombre; }
```

¿Cómo le proporcionamos la variable `nombre`? Obviamente no se la podemos facilitar como parámetro porque `std::count_if` nos exige que la firma sea `bool func(Nodo*)`. Pues bien, la solución clásica consiste en crear un objeto que implemente el operador función:

```
struct CompararNodo
{
  const std::string nombre;

  CompararNodo(
      std::string const& nombre)
    : nombre(nombre)
  {}

  bool operator()(Nodo* nodo)
  {
    return nodo->cadena == nombre;
  }
};
```

Un ejemplo de uso podría ser el siguiente:

```
CompararNodo comparador("test");
if( comparador(nodo1) ) // Devuelve true si nodo1->cadena == test
// ...
```

En *C++11* y posteriores esta misma funcionalidad se podría conseguir con una ***lambda*** con estado. La ventaja evidente es que evitamos crear el objeto `CompararNodo`:

```
std::string nombre = "test";
auto lambda = [&nombre] (Nodo* nodo) { return nodo->cadena == nombre; };

if( lambda(nodo1) )
// ...
```

Otra forma usando *lambdas* anidadas. La ventaja de este método es que la variable `nombre` queda oculta.

```
auto lambda1 = [](std::string nombre)
{ return [&](Nodo* nodo){ return nodo->cadena == nombre; }; }

auto lambda2 = lambda1("test");
if( lambda2(nodo1) )
// ...
```

**5. Contar el número de apariciones**

Ya tenemos todo hecho y únicamente nos falta usarlo. Para realizar el conteo de nodos basta con un código tal que:

```
std::string nombre;
std::cout << "Nombre a buscar: ";
std::cin >> nombre;
int repetidos = std::count_if(arbol.begin(),arbol.end(),CompararNodo(nombre));

std::cout << "La cadena " << nombre << " se repite " << repetidos << " vece(s)\n";
```

Nota que para este ejemplo he usado la clase `CompararNodo`. No he hecho uso de funcionalidad *C++11* o posterior porque la pregunta no indica que dichos estándares estén disponibles.

**Ventajas de esta solución**

La principal ventaja es que una vez abstraída la estructura interna de la clase `Arbol` mediante los iteradores es prácticamente trivial añadir funcionalidades nuevas que requieran moverse por el árbol.

Comment: Mágnifica. No esperaba menos :-) Tal vez, por buscarle algún pero, alguna referencia a posibles implementaciones alternativas del `iterator`, usando, por ejemplo, `::std::stack` para ahorrarnos el `nodo.padre`; como digo, por poner algún pero. Y muy *a la manera C++ de hacer las cosas*. Como siempre, tus respuestas no defraudan.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma. Lo de las implementaciones de `std::iterator` lo deje de lado para no complicar la respuesta más de lo necesario. Si es cierto que se puede hacer de forma más elegante... Pero me daba la sensación de que así me iba a dispersar demasiado con las explicaciones sobre lo que va por detrás... Eso sí, gracias por la crítica.

Comment: Ya te digo que es *por poner alguna queja*. Efectivamente, sería diluir demasiado lo esencial. Me será difícil superarte, pero estoy en ello ;-)