# En un array, ¿ mejor método de actualizar índices al propio array?

Tags: c++, c, algoritmos

Llevo un par de días dándole vueltas a esto:

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
struct Dato {
  char valor;
  int referido1, referido2;
};

Dato *array;
```

Y construyo un *arreglo* en memoria con la siguiente estructura:

```
[{'a',-1,-1},{'a',2,3},{'c',4,5},{'c',0,-1},{'d',-1,-1},{'e',-1,-1}]
```

Como se ve, es una lista de `Dato`, ordenada por su campo `valor`.

Los campos `referido1` y `referido2` hacen referencia a los índices del propio arreglo: `array[2].referido1 == 4 -> array[4]`.

Los datos reales son aleatorios, pero el *arreglo* mantiene su estructura; siempre estará ordenado por el campo `valor`. Además, tengo que permitir la introducción dinámica de datos.

Ahora, el problema. Al insertar un nuevo `Dato` con su campo `valor = 'b'`, quedaría así:

```
[{'a',-1,-1},{'a',2,3},{'b',-1,-1},{'c',4,5},{'c',0,-1},{'d',-1,-1},{'e',-1,-1}]
```

Esto me **invalida** los índices de varios de los `Dato` ya presentes. En este ejemplo, invalidaría los índices en `[1]`, `[4]`, `[5]`, ...

Actualmente, los *reconstruyo* mediante un `while( )`, recorriendo **todo** el arreglo, comprobando si el índice apunta a un elemento de índice **posterior o igual** al insertado; si es asi, añado 1 al índice correspondiente.

La pregunta es: ¿ alguna forma **mas rápida**, que no implique recorrer **todo el arreglo** ? La `struct Dato` se puede modificar, pero los campos indicados **son obligatorios**; puedo añadir, pero no eliminar.

Admito respuestas en `C`, `C++`, y hasta ideas generales, siempre que las entienda, claro.

**EDITO**

Esto está relacionado con la pregunta [¿Cómo recorrer un árbol binario buscando nodos con el mismo dato?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13734/c%C3%B3mo-recorrer-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-buscando-nodos-con-el-mismo-dato/) y mi respuesta a la misma. La respuesta en si es una *masturbación mental*, **extremadamente** lenta en la inserción de elementos, pero **muy rápida** al buscarlos y *contarlos*.

Me quedó la duda de si sería posible mejorar algo la inserción, manteniendo *mas o menos* las ideas originales expuestas en la pregunta y en la respuesta: usar solo un `std::vector`, sin estructuras de datos adicionales, y que el elemento `Dato` sea algo parecido a un *nodo* en un *árbol binario*.

El código fuente utilizado en mis pruebas; es un *armazón* fácilmente modificable. **No** he *atinado* a hacerlo mas corto. Esta realizado en C++, y compila con

> g++ -std=c++98 -Wall

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib> // rand( ) y srand( ).

struct Data {
  int value;
  std::ptrdiff_t left, right;

  Data( int v );
  bool operator<( const Data &o ) const { return value < o.value; }
};

// Facilita la lectura.
typedef std::vector< Data > VectorType;
typedef VectorType::iterator Iterator;

// Auxiliar para indicar quién es el padre.
// iter -> iterador al padre.
// left -> 'true' o 'false'.
struct ParentPos {
  Iterator iter;
  bool left;

  ParentPos( ) : iter( ), left( false ) { }
  ParentPos( const Iterator &i, bool l ) : iter( i ), left( l ) { }
  ParentPos &operator=( const ParentPos &o ) {
    iter = o.iter;
    left = o.left;
    return *this;
  }
};

VectorType Vector;
static unsigned Steps = 0; // Para comparar los resultados.

// Para volcado del vector.
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &, const Data & );
// Las posibles optimizaciones
void PreInsert( Iterator &, const Data &, ParentPos &);
void PostInsert( Iterator &, const Data &, ParentPos & );

// Por si queremos volcar el vector durante las pruebas.
void Dump( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) {
  Iterator iter = Vector.begin( );

  while( iter != Vector.end( ) ) {
    os << *iter << std::endl;
    ++ iter;
  }
}

// Seleciona aleatoriamente quién será el padre del dato.
// Recibe el ÍNDICE en el que se insertará.
// Modifica el padre para que referencie al hijo.
// Devuelve un 'Iterator' al padre.
ParentPos SelectParent( ptrdiff_t pos ) {
  bool left = rand( ) & 1; // ¿ hijo left o right ?
  Iterator iter = Vector.begin( );

  while( true ) {
    if( left && ( iter->left == -1 ) ) {
      iter->left = pos;
      break;
    }

    if( ( !left ) && ( iter->right == -1 ) ) {
      iter->right = pos;
      break;
    }

    ++iter;
  }

  return ParentPos( iter, left );
}

void Insert( int v ) {
  Data aux( v );
  ParentPos pp;
  Iterator END;
  Iterator BEGIN;
  Iterator iter;

  std::cout << "Añadido " << v << " en la pos ";

  // Para evitar invalidar los iteradores, nos aseguramos
  // de que tengamos espacio para 1 elemento mas.
  Vector.reserve( Vector.size( ) + 1 );

  END = Vector.end( );
  BEGIN = Vector.begin( );

  // Buscamos el final de su grupo.
  iter = std::upper_bound( BEGIN, END, aux );

  std::cout << std::distance( BEGIN, iter );

  // Si 'Vector' NO ESTÁ VACÍO, escogemos un padre.
  if( !Vector.empty( ) ) {
    pp = SelectParent( std::distance( BEGIN, iter ) );
    std::cout << " al padre " << pp.iter->value;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  // Caso FÁCIL; añadir al final del vector.
  // NO cambia el orden relativo de los enlaces.
  // NO es necesario optimizar nada.
  if( iter == END ) {
    Vector.push_back( aux );
  } else {
  // Caso normal. SE INSERTA EN ALGÚN PUNTO DISTINTO DEL FINAL.
    PreInsert( iter, aux, pp );
    Vector.insert( iter, aux );
    PostInsert( iter, aux, pp );
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  // int count = 4; // 1 mas de los que queramos.

  // Para tener resultados reproducibles.
  srand( 0 );
  // Borrar la pantalla (¡ Linux !)
  std::cout << "\033c";

//  while( --count )
//    Insert( rand( ) % 10 );
  Insert( 3 );
  Insert( 6 );
  Dump( );
  Insert( 5 );
  Dump( );

  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Pasos: " << Steps << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

/***********************
*                      *
* Constructor de Data. *
*                      *
************************/
Data::Data( int v ) :
  value( v ),
  left( -1 ),
  right( -1 )
{

}
/*********************************************************
*                                                        *
* Método a implementar para el volcado de cada elemento. *
*                                                        *
**********************************************************/
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const Data &dat ) {
  os << " Value: ";
  os << std::setw( 2 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << dat.value;
  os << " [" << dat.left << "][" << dat.right << "]";

  // La función 'Dump' añade al final un 'std::endl'.
  return os;
}

/*********************************************************
*                                                        *
*  Funciónes a reimplementar para buscar optimizaciones. *
*                                                        *
**********************************************************/
// pos -> Posición en la que se insertará.
// d -> Dato.
// parent -> padre.
void PreInsert( Iterator &pos, const Data &d, ParentPos &parent ) {
  Iterator iter = Vector.begin( );
  ptrdiff_t relative = std::distance( Vector.begin( ), pos );

  while( iter != Vector.end( ) ) {
    // Para mantener el orden relativo de los índices.
    if( parent.iter == iter ) {
      if( parent.left ) {
        if( iter->right >= relative )
          ++iter->right;
      } else {
        if( iter->left >= relative )
          ++iter->left;
      }

      ++iter;
      continue;
    }

    if( iter != pos ) {
      if( iter->left >= relative )
        ++iter->left;

      if( iter->right >= relative )
        ++iter->right;
    }

    ++iter;
  }
}

// pos -> Posición en la que se insertó.
// d -> dato.
// parent -> padre.
void PostInsert( Iterator &pos, const Data &d, ParentPos &parent ) {

}
```

Ese código recorre el `std::vector` **completo** en cada nueva inserción.

Comment: Cada elemento en el array tiene al menos dos referencias, una lineal (la posición del elemento en el array) y la otra espacial (las "referencias", que vienen a ser una especie de punteros a las posiciones referenciadas). Insertar un nuevo elemento implica un nuevo orden lineal, y la necesidad de reconstruir la cadena de referencias. No veo que esté contemplado que un nuevo elemento insertado sea referenciado por elementos preexistentes, y tampoco que tenga en sí mismo referencias a otros elementos. La definición de tu modelo parece incompleta, al menos.

Comment: @asdasdasd ese modelo es una simplificación del real, que puedes encontrar en mi respuesta a http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13734/c%c3%b3mo-recorrer-un-%c3%a1rbol-binario-buscando-nodos-con-el-mismo-dato Para buscar optimizaciones, con la simplificación basta. El como se establecen las relaciones entre los elementos no tiene importancia.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente cuando optimizas en velocidad penalizas en consumo de memoria y al revés y esto es así porque, muchas veces, optimizar en velocidad es algo que se consigue precalculando información y guardando resultados temporales.

Una forma alternativa de a tu algoritmo actual la puedes encontrar mapeando los referidos. Es decir, imagínate que los nodos 3 y 4 tienen al nodo 6 como referido, en este mapa habrá dos registros que indicarán que si el nodo 6 sufre un cambio de índice habrá que avisar a los nodos 3 y 4:

```
// Clave -> Indice afectado
// Valor -> Lista de indices a actualizar
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mapeoReferidos;
Dato *array;
```

Entonces, al insertar un elemento la operativa quedaría así:

```
void ElementoAInsertar(int indice)
{
  std::for_each(std::next(mapeoReferidos.begin(),indice),
                mapeoReferidos.end(),
  [&](const std::vector<int>& referidos)
  {
    for( int indiceRef : referidos )
    {
      // No me gusta repetir codigo... es malo para el negocio
      auto lambda = [](int& referido, int indice)
      { if( referido == indice ) referido = indice+1; };

      Dato* dato = array[indiceRef];
      lambda(dato->referido1,indice);
      lambda(dato->referido2,indice);
    }
  });
}
```

Fíjate en el nombre de la función. Está pensada para ser llamada justo **antes** de insertar el nuevo elemento. Una vez insertado el elemento los índices ya han cambiado y las operaciones me parecen un poquito más incómodas.

He optado realizar el mapeo con vectores anidados porque la idea el índice de cada elemento coincida en `array` y en `mapeoReferidos`. Es decir, `mapeoReferidos[i]` te debería devolver la lista de nodos que hacen referencia al nodo ubicado en `datos[i]`.

Faltaría el código para rellenar el mapa cada vez que se añade un nuevo elemento... pero saber cómo haces esa parte es arriesgado ponerte código.

La penalización en este caso estaría en que si un elemento cambia sus referidos habrá que actualizar el mapa para que refleje siempre valores actualizados.

La supuesta ventaja es que ahora no tienes que recorrer todo el vector buscando coincidencias... y que no tienes que modificar la estructura `Dato`.

Comment: Es para la pregunta del árbol, y no quiero convertirla en un catálogo de soluciones sobre optimización. Me conformaría con poder optimizar *de forma mas o menos simple* el bucle de actualización de índices, pero creo que no será posible, sin, como dices, aumentar el uso de memoria. Por otra parte, gran respuesta, como siempre. Mas de uno la aprovechará. +1

Comment: @Trauma podrías integrar el vector en la estructura. Así cada nodo tendría un vector con los índices de los nodos que se refieren a el... pero me parece un diseño un poco más engorroso.

Comment: Creo que no vale. La suma de `nodos + lista de referentes` sería casi igual al total de nodos. Una mejora residual, en comparación con el uso de memoria. Al final, creo que no hay muchas mejoras posibles, sin usar otras estructuras adicionales.

Comment: Partiendo de tu idea, tengo algo. Si pongo un atributo ' padre` en cada nodo, puesto que cada nodo solo tiene 1 padre, podriamos subir *hacia arriba*. Hay que actualizar los nodos **antes** de insertar, comenzado en el punto de inserción. El problema es que se necesita un atributo `ya_modificado`, con lo que hay que recorrer los nodos posteriores al insertado **2** veces. Sería un *caso especial optimizable*, si el punto de inserción está en el centro del array o más arriba. Demasiado trabajo para optimizar el 50% teórico de los casos, y, como tu dices, sería *dispersarse* demasiado. Puff...

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo mínimo ejecutable se podría mirar con más tranquilidad

Answer (score 1):

Existe una forma de realizar este proceso de manera super eficiente, pero es bastante engorrosa y no creo que sea viable explicarla aquí. Si quieres, dale un vistazo a la estructura de datos avanzados ABI (Arbol binario indexado), o BIT, por sus siglas en inglés. Mi propuesta más sencilla sería que en lugar de guardar los preferidos como índices de un arreglo, los guardes como punteros a los elementos que quieres, y así vas a tener siempre la referencia, independientemente del lugar que ocupe dentro del arreglo. Sería algo asi:

```
struct Dato {
    char valor;
    Dato *preferido1, *preferido2;
}
```

Esto se conoce como estructura autorreferenciada, puesto que, como su nombre lo indica, tiene referencias a elementos de su mismo tipo en su interior.

NOTA: Debes tener cuidado, en caso de usar este método, con la parte de la asignacion dinámica de memoria, teniendo siempre presente que debes liberar todo el espacio que reservaste durante la ejecución del programa.

Espero que haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @IsaacVega, pero eso es precisamente lo que no puedo hacer. Por las molestias, y la ausencia de indicaciones por mi parte, +1. La historia viene de aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13734/c%C3%B3mo-recorrer-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-buscando-nodos-con-el-mismo-dato/44878#44878 y lo que pretendo es acelerar las inserciones, que son O( n ).  Estoy mirando ABI.